# Pdf generators from an xml template?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Are there any PDF generators out there be it commercial or open source which can be used for research purposes? That i can use such as pdfnow.com or any standalone desktop apps which allow me to generate a PDF from a XML template. I have tried researching but there is allot of ambiguity going around.

Answer (score 0):

Applidok is generating PDF based on an original (raw) PDF, a template definition and dynamic/user data (e.g. from a form): http://go.applidok.com/en/howitworks.gz.html

Template format there is JSON, not XML, but approach is the same.